# `quantile()` making numbers up

Tags: r

Why does

```
quantile(c(0.1,0.2))
```

give

```
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
0.100 0.125 0.150 0.175 0.200
```

while in fact there are not values 0.125, 0.150, and 0.175 in the dataset?

Comment: Perhaps you want `quantile(c(0.1,0.2), type = 1)`. See the help for `?quantile`. The default type 7 creates a continuous distribution from the given data and outputs sample quantiles corresponding to that.

Answer (score 5):

upon doing `?quantile`, you'll see that the default method for the result would be from a method of estimating sample quantiles from a **continuous sample**. If you want `quantile()` to return values strictly from the set (**discontinuous** or like discrete), you could do

```
quantile(c(0.1,0.2),type=1)
```